# Guardar datos en dos base de datos diferentes con Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, lumen

Tengo dos APIS desarrolladas y utilizo Lumen, pero tengo un problema que lo voy a plantear de la siguiente manera:
La `API 1` `obtiene` los datos desde la `base de datos 1`, envia esos datos a la `API 2` para que ella pueda `guardar` los datos en la `base de datos 2`.
Es decir que una de las API's consume datos de una bse de datos y luego por medio de un endpoint enviamos los datos para que se guarden en una segunda base de datos.
El problemsa que estoy teniendo es que el esta guardando los datos en la base de datos 1 y no en la base de datos 2.
Las variables de entornos tienen configuraciones diferentes para conectarse a base de datos distintas.
Espero haber explicado bien ...

Saludo

Comment: Se puede obtener la conexión para indicar a donde deben llegar los datos al momento de constuir la query o se puede indicar de forma dinámica si es que usas modelos a que conexión viajar, ¿puedes proveer mas datos al respecto de tus queries?

Comment: @BetaM necesito llevar datos de una API a otra API y almacenarlos en una base de datos que esta en la segunda API. Tengo creado los metodos necesarios para grabar los datos en la base de datos conectada a la segunda API, tambien todas las relaciones en la segunda API. Pero cuando envio el payload en vez de guardarse los datos en la base de datos de la segunda API, se almacenas en la base de datos conectada a la primera API

Comment: Los dos lumen tiene dos .env, el de la segunda API me toma la configuracion de la base de datos de la primera API